# In QT application on LXDE resize() does not work as expected

Tags: desktop, qt

I create a QT application by QT 4.8.2 under Gnome environment. After I changed my desktop environment from Gnome to LXDE, I can not run it. The interface is changed. I can not see the button and toolbar in it. I deleted resize(maximumSize()), then it works well. Anyone can interpret it?

Thanks.

Comment: Screenshots would help.

Comment: What error messages do you get if any?  Does the process start?

Comment: There is no any error message. Actually, the application works well. Just the interface is wrong. I changed my code. A line "resize(maximumSize());" was deleted. Now, it works well. But, I am wondering, why resize()did not work.

Comment: @HXGuo Could you please edit the question so it contains the updated information about `resize(maximumSize());`? Then new title should probably contain: *In QT application on LXDE resize() does not work as expected*. Thank you.